# Felsen vs Stein

Tags: translation, difference

*Stein* and *Felsen* both translate to *stone* in English, but are they interchangeable? When I google images for both, I get mostly small palm-sized stones for *Stein* and something that I would call *boulder* for *Felsen.* Also I saw in my text-book expressions like:

> Dieser steile Felsen ist sehr imposant.

but nothing with *steiler Stein,* which might signify that *der Felsen* are generally big in size.

So my question is: Can I translate *Felsen* with *boulder* and *Stein* with *a small stone?*

Please refrain from going into scientific definitions. This isn’t geological question. I just want to know how native speakers perceive the difference.

Comment: As I recently found out, the meaning of the English terms for stones of different sizes varies considerably between regions. Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85817/is-there-a-significant-difference-between-rock-and-stone, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5931/whats-the-difference-between-rock-and-stone

Comment: As a mnemonic you may use: You can jump from a `Felsen` into the sea [in Acapulco], and – after reaching the shore – you can pick up a 

flat `Stein` and skim it over the water surface.

Comment: Stein can also translate to "rock", also "Felsen" can be a "rock". Große Steine in einem Fluß werden z. B. als rock übersetzt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your observation is right as far as i can tell. One would talk about a "Felsen" like in "boulder" in english. It typically refers to a bigger sort of stone while a stone would be something palm sized.

I would usally use "Felsen" for a big stone which can´t be moved in an easy way.

Comment: *Felsen* is also always in its natural, "grown" form, while *Stein* can have been shaped into form or even be man-made - That is pretty close to English, there's a "Grabstein" or "Tombstone", but no "Grabfelsen" or "Tomb rock", also see "Backstein" == "Brick"

Comment: @tofro this is a great addition!

Comment: And, "Felsen" typically refers to a part of the fixed landscape, whereas "Stein" typically denotes something movable.